# Debug project on Virtual Machine with xDebug

Tags: php, apache, vagrant, virtual-machine, xdebug

I have a Virtual Machine set up by Vagrant. It's Centos 7. Besides Apache and mod_php I installed xDebug and its configurations looks like this:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable = On
xdebug.remote_autostart = On
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_mode = req
xdebug.remote_connect_back = On
xdebug.idekey = "netbeans-xdebug"
```

I set up a virtual host for my project, and when I pull it out in the browser, I get it working. xDebug works perfectly.

Then I want to use Vagrant Share to make my project reachable from the Internet. When I start this service, the site is available via my-temporary-domain.vagrantshare.com. Everything seems working fine. But I'm not able to debug.

What is the problem I cannot see? What should I configure to get xDebug doing its job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I figured out the solution.

My guest machine has a static IP 192.168.1.2. My host one -- 192.168.1.1
When I set

```
xdebug.remote_connect_back = Off
```

which is default, btw. And make

```
xdebug.remote_host = 192.168.1.1
```

it works as expected. I assume it's because of xDebug concept that I didn't completely understand. This article helped:
http://walkah.net/blog/debugging-php-with-vagrant/